# Apache error - localhost:150 - Not a Listen port

Tags: apache, wamp, port, virtualhost

I'm setting up a web server, but I'm new in this kind of stuff. And I kinda set it up, but I get the following problem when i enter my localhost page:

- localhost:150 - Not a Listen port
  Error(s) See below
  Port :150 used for the VirtualHost is not an Apache define variable

Also, when I press localhost on my WAMP, it doesn't work, but when I enter localhost:150 to google, it works.

I have tried changing ports to 150 in httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf .

I want to run my localhost without this error. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a late response, but I hope it helps someone. I've had the same issue and resolved it by finding the wampserver file in c:\ (you may have downloaded it to a different directory) and edited the 'add_vhost' file. I found it in c:\wamp/www/

Inside of the add_vhost file, you need to find every instance of the number 80 and ONLY edit the instances that pertain to Port 80 (I assume that you were having an issue with port 80 and that's why you've changed your port). 
There should only be two if-statements in which it occurs: [e.g., if($vh_port == '80' || $vh_port == $c_UsedPort) ]. In my case, I swapped out '80' for desired port '8081'.

You will also need to check your httpd-vhosts.conf file (in Apache on wamp server) and confirm that your document root and directory are pointing to the correct path. Hint: it should be the same path where you found your add_vhost file. 
E.g., 
DocumentRoot "c:\wamp64/www"

Lastly, you should right click the green wamp server icon and select tools, then select 'use a port other than 80' and change it to 150.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to do it is to open `httpd.conf` and add under the Listen section:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:YOUR_PORT
Listen [::0]:YOUR_PORT
```

And restart the server